# recreate a container after updating dockerfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a `dev.Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` file. When I run `docker-compose up` it runs the old container even if I have updated the `dev.Dockerfile`. How can I update the container? Is there a way to update the container after running `docker-compose up` ?
Here is my `dev.Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1
MAINTAINER Abraham Kuri <kurenn@icalialabs.com>

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN set -ex \
  && curl -sL "https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x" | bash - \
  && apt-get -y install nodejs \
  && npm install -g bower

RUN gem install bundler -v 1.11.2 --no-ri --no-rdoc

ENV PATH=/usr/src/app/bin:$PATH LANG=C.UTF-8

ADD Gemfile* /usr/src/app/

# Run dependencies install commands
RUN bundle
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
  redis-data:       # The redis data store volume
    driver: local
  gems:
    driver: local

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.7
    ports:
      # We'll bind our host's port 6379 to redis's port 6379, so we can use
      # any explorer to read the database:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      # We'll store the redis data in the 'redis-data' volume we defined:
      - redis-data:/var/lib/redis
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5.1
    ports:
      # We'll bind our host's port 5432 to postgres's port 5432, so we can use
      # our database IDEs with it:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      # We'll store the postgres data in the 'postgres-data' volume we defined:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: P4Ssw0rD!

  # The job processor container - we'll use this as a base for the rest of the
  # containers:
  jobs: &app
    # Specify the directory from where all commands sent to the container will be
    # issued to where the code is mounted:
    image: catarse/catarse:development
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q default
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile

    volumes:
      # Mount our app code directory (".") into our app containers at the
      # "/usr/src/app" folder:
      - .:/usr/src/app

      # Mount the 'gems' volume on the folder that stores bundled gems:
      - gems:/usr/local/bundle

    # Keep the stdin open, so we can attach to our app container's process
    # and do things such as byebug, etc:
    stdin_open: true

    # Enable sending signals (CTRL+C, CTRL+P + CTRL+Q) into the container:
    tty: true

    # Link to our postgres and redis containers, so they can be visible from our
    # app containers:
    depends_on:
      # We'll include a link to the 'db' (postgres) container, making it
      # visible from the container using the 'db' hostname:
      - db
      - redis

    # Specify environment variables available for our app containers. We'll leave
    # a YML anchor in case we need to override or add more variables if needed on
    # each app container:
    environment: &app_environment
      LANG: 'C.UTF-8'

      # We'll set the DATABASE_URL environment variable for the app to connect
      # to our postgres container - no need to use a 'config/database.yml' file.
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:P4Ssw0rD!@db:5432/docker_rails_dev?pool=25&encoding=unicode&schema_search_path=public,partitioning
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379

      # We'll set the RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV environment variables to
      # 'development', so our app containers will start in 'development' mode
      # on this compose project:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      RACK_ENV: development

    # We'll specify a dotenv file for docker-compose to load more environment
    # variables into our app containers. This dotenv file would normally contain
    # sensitive data (API keys & secrets, etc) which SHOULD NOT be committed into
    # Git.
    # Keep in mind that any changes in this file will require a container restart
    # in order to be available on the app containers:
    env_file:
      - dev.env
  web:
    <<: *app
    command: rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -P /tmp/rails2.pid
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
       # App Guard: Keeps running tests on a separate process:
  test:
    <<: *app # We copy from &app, and override:
    environment:
      <<: *app_environment
      # Override the app environment for this container:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:P4Ssw0rD!@db:5432/docker_rails_test?pool=25&encoding=unicode&schema_search_path=public,partitioning
      RACK_ENV: test
      RAILS_ENV: test
      SECRET_KEY_BASE_TEST: "600bac98dabba98b903ce4c4d25e48f34920e09f43d3ff61a1005e0f500d5a0e38e25f70ef78e0a8b5475d4ff21cc553e7c07f6565f1c8773165350345fbbc56"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `docker-compose build` to force a rebuild of your containers, for the compose file. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/

you can also `docker-compose down` to deconstruct the composed setup: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/ - and then `docker-compose up` again.

can also manually remove the containers and images, and run `docker-compose up` again